# Which network management system (NMS) to choose?

Tags: networking, monitoring, performance-monitoring, network-monitoring, network-management

I need to integrate NMS in large enterprise system for data collection purposes. Primary requirements:

- collection by SNMP
- great scalability (up to 1,000 devices with 1,000 interfaces each)
- failover
- data storage in Oracle DBMS
- integration API (configuration, data access)

Any ideas would be appreciated...

Comment: monitoring what kit?

Comment: DSLAM-s devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we have chosen [WebNMS](http://www.webnms.com/). It satisfies most of our requirements, and it is Java-based (same as our enterprise system).

I appreciate all answers, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A variety of tools exist in the space.

You can look at [OpenNMS](http://OpenNMS.org) (it uses PostgreSQL), OpenView, [NetVigil](http://www.netscout.com/docs/support/NetScout_mc_NetVigil_FAQ.pdf)<sub><sup>(pdf)</sup></sub> ([NetVigil comparison](http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/15426)) (uses MySQL, I believe), [Nagios](http://nagios.org), [Zenoss](http://Zenoss.com) (don't know what it uses), and more.

What is your budget? How much time and effort are you willing to expend?

You might also want to look at something like HP NA (https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-271-273^14681_4000_100).

Answer (score 3):

Icinga, which is a Nagios fork, allows Oracle DB's. Not entirely sure if Nagios does too. Advantage of Icinga, for me, is the fact that their new web interface (still in beta though!) simply kicks ass. It's extremely customizable, and has everything we need.

That being said, it's a monitoring system, and not a management system.

I'm not sure what you mean with "integration API (configuration, data access)". Do you want to set certain parameters through the NMS ? In that case, Nagios, Icinga and Zenoss won't be for you.

As far as scalability goes... it depends how you build your configs. If you put it all in 1 file, which is the default install and many unexperienced people seem to do (I'm unexperienced with this software myself and still setting it up for us, but I do realize this will cause problems in the future) you will end up shooting yourself in the foot. Split them up and use the inheritance functions!

Comment: Actually, I might have confused Zenoss with another Nagios-based system, can't come up with the name right now.

Comment: Yes, nagios also has a good selection of Oracle-interrogative plugins

Answer (score 1):

HP openview will work if your stuck with using oracle

Answer (score 1):

Checkout NetValence CAPSTONE @ www.netvalence.net

This probably fits your need of SNMP, Scalability, DB support etc.

I have evaluated this product and this is exceedingly good.